# how could I use gvim through ssh two hops

Tags: vimrc, gvim, ssh

I sometimes need to work on remote server which does not have x11 installed and thus I cannot use vim with its full features. I want to work on remote server with the gvim installed to my local machine. What is not convenient is that I need two hops to access my server through some middle machine. That means I can only access server like this:  local -> middle -> server.

How could I do it please ?

=====
Edit: 
Here is the specific case: 
I have to access my remote server via middle server, and I have no way to bypass the middle server.

I do not have a home directory at the middle server, so I cannot configure and use the middle server. It only plays the role of some entrance.

I do not mind whether I have to use gvim, I am considering gvim because it has built-in clipboard function which is better than the terminal vim. I can compile terminal vim from source, but I do not have x11 in both the remote server and the middle server.

The core problem is how could I copy contents from the remote vim?

Comment: Note that gVim is not Vim with its full features: you can have a terminal Vim with its full features. Now for your problem, maybe you could try to use a remote file system like [SSHFS](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSHFS) to mount the server on your local machine (I think it is possible to do it with a hop but I never tested it)

Comment: I don't have any extensive experience with ssh, but I would say you're better off with terminal Vim which is more robust than its GUI counterpart anyway. But if you're really devoted then you could maybe look for something similar to what Emacs does with Tramp which is basically using `scp` etc. under the hood.

Comment: @klaus Thanks, the problem with terminal vim is that: I cannot copy the contents out if I open a file in the remote server, since the server has no x11 installed and there is a ssh hop between my local machine and the remote server. Do you have any suggestions about using the terminal version vim?

Comment: I don't have any suggestion, sorry. As I've said, I've little experience. But for ease of others, you should state the matter about ssh hop, i.e. do you want to use the middle server or do you *have* to but don't *want* to, for other people here. And about the suggestions, from my little to no knowledge, I think I would just use mouse to copy stuff from terminal. The terminal emulator is in my local machine, it doesn't matter that the terminal is a viewport to the remote machine. But of course, your case seems to be more complex. So, maybe add your use cases, i.e. your workflow here and (cont)

Comment: (contd.) state clearly what you *want* vs. what you *have*. Maybe even post your concerns on [r/vim](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/), there are some people there with wide range of experiences.

Comment: Use netrw to locally access files using scp/sftp. Configure ssh to work properly using the `ProxyJump` configuration setting

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Thanks for responding. Would you please be more specific and write an example in the the answer?

Comment: @coincheung configure using ssh_config and the `ProxyJump` configuration. See manpage or examples in the net. Make sure, that you can simply use ssh foreign host directly (which will then instruct to proxy through the middle server). Once this works, use netrw (read the help at `:h netrw`).

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Hi , I have just tried to config my `~/.ssh/config` and I can now use `ssh target` to replace the long command of `ssh -t name@middle -p1123 name@remote`. However, I cannot use `vim scp://target/~/test.txt`, I got the error message of `bash: /usr/bin/scp: Permission denied`. I do not have a `/home/name` directory on the middle server, and the `scp` command is banned in both the middle server and the remote server. So how could I use netrw in this case please?

Comment: well if scp is disabled, can you use sftp?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Yes, that command works. Now since I have configured the `~/.ssh/config`, I thus mount the remote directory to my local mount point. Now I can work locally to edit the remote file. Do you think the netrw method provides better performance than the sshfs method?

Comment: I don't know, since I don't use it.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Does netrw have the problem of network latency when switching between buffers? I tried the mount method, it works well when I edit the file, but the latency is too obvious when I open a file and switch between buffers and even jump between the split buffers with `ctrl+w+l`. So it may not be a good method, does netrw has the same problem ?

Comment: @coincheung netrw "downloads" the file and let Vim edit it locally. I have never used it for serious editing however, so you have to try yourself.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, it's fairly easy. I practice, there are a few gotcha's. Let's walk through this step by step, and I'll tell you what to look for. Once you validate that everything is correct, you ought to be able to do this lickity-split.
Note: I use Red Hat/CentOS. You may have to make slight variations in commands for your environment.

On "local" make sure `xhost` is set correctly. Easy way:
`[me@local]$ xhost +`

For convenience, check your DISPLAY variable:
`[me@local]$ echo $DISPLAY`
You should see something like `:0` or `:0.1`
   (More later)

Next, use ssh with X-Display forwarding:
`[me@local]$ ssh -X middle -l me`
Alternately: `ssh -X me@middle`

Now, here it is important to ensure that your DISPLAY variable is set correctly. On some machines, the login files are configured to set your DISPLAY variable for you. **This will break the X-Display forwarding!!**
`[me@middle]$ echo $DISPLAY`
The **correct** setting will look like this:
`localhost:10`  or even
`localhost:11.1`
The **incorrect** setting will look something like this:
`*starting_hostname*:0.0`
If you have an incorrect setting, you cannot manually change the DISPLAY environment back. You *must* find where your login scripts on the "middle" host are changing it and leave it the default.

Third, ssh using X-Display forwarding into server:
`[me@middle]$ ssh -X me@server`
Check your DISPLAY variable again. The same caveat as above applies here. It must be *localhost:[number]*

At this point, check that your remote display is working correctly by starting *any* GUI program and validate that screen appears on the local box.

Once you are sure everything is configured, you can run these commands:
`[me@local]$ xhost +
[me@local]$ ssh -X me@middle
[me@middle]$ ssh -X me@server
[me@server]$ gvim my_filename`

Additional info:
Port 6000 needs to be open between all of the boxes. That is the X-Display forwarding port.

The X-Display programs & libraries need to be installed on "server." (OS Dependent, can't help you here). IF you program (gVIM) calls the "draw a box api" and the "server" OS doesn't know what that is, it will never work.
(Really what happens is, "server" application says "Draw a box with these coordinates." The "server" X-window system says "OK. But, I don't have a monitor ... oh, wait, I'll just draw the box on the 'localhost' monitor."

"server" and "local" have to have compatible X-windowing systems. I've seen issues where Solaris or AIX talking to a CentOS box doesn't always work.

Unless you are using IP addresses in lieu of hostnames, each of your machines need to be able to resolve all 3 host names to an IP address. Usually, I just ensure that all 3 host/IP names in /etc/hosts. This sounds odd, but I have seen this be an issue. And, FWIW, add FQDN & Short Hostname to /etc/hosts.